# Apache2 not running when Passenger is enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, apache2, passenger, rbenv

I upgraded Ubuntu to 18.04. After the upgrade Apache complained that libcurl3 is required for the present version of Passenger (so the existing version of Passenger was outdated since libcurl4 now comes with Ubuntu 18.04). So I installed the latest version of Passenger (without previously removing the existing one, if this is important). After the installation I couldn't start Apache anymore.

**systemctl status apache2.service** says

> apache2.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.

As soon as I disable Passenger the Apache starts without any problems.

I already reinstalled Passenger (i.e. unistalled and installed again). But when installing the mod again it's not generating the required passenger.conf into the mods-available folder. And each time I copy the old conf into the folder and enable the mod the Apache doesn't start. I'm lost...

I have rbenv installed and already changed the ruby dir in the passenger.conf:

```
PassengerDefaultRuby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

Any ideas what to try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some nights of experimenting I found out it was a version conflict. By default the newest Passenger version 6.0.2 was installed. This version for some reason didn't work with my Apache version. After installing the latest 5.X version of Passenger the Apache runs smoothly!